# String Left & Mid Manipulation in a For Loop Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting

I am writing a batch file with a for loop and am having trouble getting the left and mid logic working. I have successfully got this logic working outside of the for loop and have attached the code here.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM ZKR

set /a value = 1000

set /a range = "%value%"
set /a secrange = "%value%"

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) do (

echo %range%

set range=%range:~0,1%
set secrange=%secrange:~1,3%

echo !range!
echo !secrange!

set "newstr=!range!.!secrange!"

echo !newstr!

PAUSE

)
```

The output is shown here.
[Split 1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kINhJ.png)

So the above cmd bat is able to split the string and then combine it with a period mark in the middle of the two split strings.

However, in my for loop I don't achieve this result. I know it may be a syntax issue but I am not sure how to fix it (I have tried a lot of different things already).

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM ZKR

set /a range = "X"
set /a secrange = "X"

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10000) do (

if %%x geq 1000 (

if %%x lss 10000 (

set "range=%%x"
set "secrange=%%x"

echo !range!
echo !secrange!

set "range=%range%:~0,1%"
echo !range!
echo %range%
set secrange=%secrange:~1,3%
echo !secrange!
echo %secrange%

set "newstr=!range!.!secrange!"
echo !newstr!

PAUSE

)

REM End x greater 1000
)


REM End for loop
)
```

I use secrange the same way as I did in the original code without the for loop. I tried to manipulate the range portion with many different syntax combos but have not been able to output the left character 1. I only am able to output 0 for both characters.

I attached the output here. [Bad Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkks.png)

I understand there is an error (Echo is Off). Please ignore that it is just based off my echo output type for my personal testing.

The important two outputs are the third and fourth line (whichever one is referring to the correct syntax). Does anyone know how to fix the syntax in order to get the left character of 1000 in the for loop and the remaining 3 zeros of the 1000?

Comment: You can't just randomly use delayed expansion.  Once you are inside a code block you have to use delayed expansion with every variable that is set and manipulated inside that code block.

Comment: Thank you, I actually was able to find out what was wrong. When you use (set secrange=%secrange:~1,3%) you have to convert it to (set "secrange=!secrange:~1,3!")